# How to get chat transcripts of specific date using azure blob storage?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-blob-storage

I am using bot framework 4 and uploaded my chatbot to microsoft teams.

I used azure blob storage to store and retrieve chat transcript which worked successfully on directline channel since each conversation had its unique conversation Id. However, in teams the conversation Id remains the same so in order to get the transcript for today's chat I would have to rely on the date parameter.

I am aware that GetTranscriptActivitiesAsync has startDate as an optional parameter but whenever I try adding today's date I get no activities returned.

Below is the code I have used. I have tried different formats for DateTimeOffset

```
    DateTimeOffset todayDate = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 12, 00, 00, TimeSpan.Zero);
DateTimeOffset currentDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(todayDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ"));
PagedResult<IActivity> tempPagedTranscript = await _myTranscripts.GetTranscriptActivitiesAsync(mailActivity.ChannelId, mailActivity.ConversationId, continuationToken, currentDate);
```

Is there something wrong in what I am doing? I just need a way to retrieve today's conversation to be able to send it vie email. Is there some other way I can get this done?

Comment: Hi @basant Could you please share the docs which you are referring to? I want to try the same sample which you referring to?

Comment: I am using the method mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.itranscriptstore.gettranscriptactivitiesasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_ITranscriptStore_GetTranscriptActivitiesAsync_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_DateTimeOffset_  and I created an implementation similar to the one mentioned here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/cfe606dffe97ca4358a9a736236db204afc7c7c2/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/22.conversation-history/ConversationHistoryBot.cs#L95

Comment: Take time offset is a UTC(Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)) time are you comparing bot time with UTC(Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)). Could you please conform?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I am not converting to UTC time, I am only changing to "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ" format. What should I do in order to compare it to UTC time?

Comment: Just to make sure all the time calculation is happening in UTC.

Comment: I have converted currentDate to UTC but its still the same issue. I am unable to get the activities of just today.